# How can I tell my netbeans build.xml where to find my servlets-api.jar?

Tags: java, servlets, ant, netbeans-8, build.xml

I am trying to resurrect on old project and get it compiling in netbeans again.  Previously - as in 7 years ago - it worked fine but now on a new rig I have to reconfigure everything. The part of the old project I am trying to recompile is just a small java utilities project - not even a full application by itself.  The project needs the servlets-api.jar  file to compile.  The IDE editor works fine - it seems to find it as I get no red lines under the javax.* import line. Only when I try to compile do I get the errors like so:

```
error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
```

My old build script is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="javautils" default="package" basedir=".">


<property file="build.properties" />

<path id="classpath">
  <pathelement path="classes"/>
  <pathelement location="${jdbc.jar}"/>
  <pathelement location="${lib.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${servletjars.home}"/>

</path>  

<presetdef name="javac">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" />
</presetdef>

<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="classes" />
</target>

<target name="prepare">
  <mkdir dir="classes" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="compile classes">
  <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <classpath refid="classpath" />
  </javac>
</target>

<target name="package"  depends="compile" description="Packages the web archive file">
        <echo message="Packaging ${app.name}'s web archive file ..."/>
        <!--
        <delete file="${basedir}/${app.name}.war"/>
        <jar jarfile="${basedir}/${app.name}.war">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/war" includes="**"/>
        </jar>
          -->
        <jar jarfile="${basedir}/${app.name}.jar">
          <fileset dir="${basedir}/classes" includes="**"/>
        </jar>
        <copy todir="${specialjars.home}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>       
        <copy todir="${standardjars.home}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>    
</target>
</project>
```

and my build.properties file is like so:

```
source.dir=src
build.dir=classes
app.name=JavaUtils
standardjars.home=f:/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib
servletjars.home=f:/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet.jar
specialjars.home=f:/javaprojects/lib
```

I know all the servletjars.home path has to be upgraded to point to the tomcat file at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\lib\servlets-api.jar  but when I do so the compile fails all the same.

I have read a ton of other posts from other users asking the same thing but so far no answers seem address my situation.  It has been so long since I did this kind of java programming I have to relearn how to work with some of this stuff.

I am now using windows 10, netbeans 8.2, java 1.8, ant 1.10.1, tomcat 8.5 and MySQL (previously I was using Oracle XE till it crashes and I couldn't revive the DB files).

Please help!

Comment: you can create a new Netbeans project and move all your resources there

Comment: Done, thanks.  Had tried that earlier by trying to make a "new java project with existing sources" but that didn't work out, but just copying the package folder into a new project did.